# select statement in C#

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access, join

Where's the problem in my code ?

```
string constr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
  + "Data Source=C:\\Users\\Simon\\Desktop\\test5\\test5\\test5\\save.mdb";

OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(constr);
string sql = "SELECT users.user_name,naziv,obroki_save.datum"
  + "FROM zivila JOIN obroki_save ON zivila.ID=obroki_save.ID_zivila"
  + "JOIN users ON obroki_save.ID_uporabnika=users.ID";
  OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
conn.Open();
OleDbDataReader reader;
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.Write(reader.GetString(0).ToString() + " ,");
    Console.Write(reader.GetString(1).ToString() + " ,");
    Console.WriteLine("");
}

reader.Close();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: @Simon: in the future, please note the problem you're having, along with your code.

Comment: are you talking about the readability? the hardcoded-in-code wrong full SQL? or any other problems? in other words if you state your specific needs it's a lot easier to help you :)

Comment: it sais that it's in the from clouse so i gues it the sql code itself

Answer (score 6):

If you run it in the debugger you can see the problem:

```
SELECT users.user_name, naziv,obroki_save.datumFROM zivila JOIN obroki_save ...
                                             ^^^^
```

You're missing spaces in your SQL. It should be this:

```
string sql = "SELECT users.user_name,naziv,obroki_save.datum " // << here
+ "FROM zivila JOIN obroki_save ON zivila.ID=obroki_save.ID_zivila " // << here
+ "JOIN users ON obroki_save.ID_uporabnika=users.ID";
```

Answer (score 2):

This is Access, so you need parentheses and you need to pick a JOIN type. LEFT and INNER are the usual choices, so:

```
SELECT users.user_name,naziv,obroki_save.datum
FROM (zivila 
LEFT JOIN obroki_save ON zivila.ID=obroki_save.ID_zivila)
LEFT JOIN users ON obroki_save.ID_uporabnika=users.ID
```

Comment: @Remou now i'm past that problem so thank you! But there is a new problem in here that happens at the line while(reader.Read()){here's the mistake}-Specified cast is not valid.